# Is it possible to scale consumers tasks over the number of partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have performance issues within our consumers. More precisely, in the WHAT is done with the messages.

Typically, we get files of 2000 lines, splitted into 6000 Kafka events.

Our topic X is configured with 10 partitions. In this case, we can start up to 10 consumers in one given group, and each consumer will be attached to one single partition until a rebalancing. Just to mention it, the ordering of the messages within the partitions is mandatory in our case.

The issue is that each message needs up to 6 seconds to be processed by a consumer. So the whole file is processed in something around 1h.

I also know that Kafka was designed for scalability, and that this scalability is managed by the number of partitions of a topic.

(An obvious solution is to refactor the code of the consumers. This is planned, but the workload of our development team is what it is, and this refactoring may not happen before several weeks.)

Adding new partitions to the topic is one solution, but existing messages will not be automatically repartitioned, and we will need to write a KS-app (or another process). That's also possible.

But I wonder if we could imagine another solution, a way to have more workers to ingest more messages in parallel?

And beyond that, can someone explain why the strategy used in Kafka (ie one consumer attached to a dedicated partition for a long while) is the right solution?

I mean, we could imagine other solutions, with more consumers than partitions: A consumer gets a message, "disconnects" from the broker, process the message, and during this time another consumer can "connect" and get a message from this same partition, "disconnect", process the message, and a 3rd consumer can connect and ........ (One guy of the team said "Hu. Kafka is not scalable. We cannot add more consumers.")

Comment: If you have 10 partitions and ordering needs to be preserved, then there is no way to increase parallelism beyond 10 consumers. Maybe ordering can be relaxed in some way?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to scale consumers tasks over the number of partition?

No.

Simply put, partitioning is your unit of scale in Kafka. If you need to process at a greater level of parallelism then you need more partitions. That's just how Kafka is designed.

As you mentioned, you can use Kafka Streams etc to repartition your topic up to a greater number of partitions, with the associated impact on ordering.

You can also use [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/ksql) to make this more simple:

```
CREATE STREAM foo_repartitioned \
  WITH (PARTITIONS=256) AS \
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

---

> "Kafka is not scalable. We cannot add more consumers."

You can add more consumers. You just need to design your topics with an appropriate level of partitions beforehand ;-)